# Tensorflow 2.0 inference with SavedModel or frozen_graph.pb

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

What is the best way to do the inference with TF models? So far it is common to use a frozen_graph.pb for inference like:

```
graph = load_graph('./path_to_frozen/frozen_graph.pb')

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    results = sess.run(
        output_operation.outputs[0],
        {input_operation.outputs[0]: img})

    sess.close()
```

When dealing with Tensorflow 2.0 I got to know about SavedModel and the infer() function in eager execution. It works like:

```py
    model = tf.saved_model.load('./path_to_savedmodel')
    infer = model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
    results = infer(img)
```

I have done tests on a CPU and option (a) takes 0.47 sec to load the model and 4.81 sec to run and option (b) takes 3x less time: 1.23 sec to load and only 0.24 sec to run.

The only difference I see is that in the savedmodel takes tensor as input, and session takes a numpy array. Other than that I am very surprised about the difference.